# Android webview: how to obtain result of evaluateJavascript in a method that invokes evaluateJavascript?

Tags: javascript, android, webview

As we know in Android, if we want to obtain the result returned by JavaScript code invocation, we can use `webview.evaluateJavascript()`. For example:

```
webview.evaluateJavascript("1+2", new ValueCallback<String>() {
     public void onReceiveValue(String value) {
        //value should be 3
     }
});
```

However, how can I further obtain the result in a method that invokes `evaluateJavascript`? For example:

```
public void myFunc() {
   String s;
   webview.evaluateJavascript("1+2", new ValueCallback<String>() {
     public void onReceiveValue(String value) {
        s = value; //This line is only for illustration, it is not syntactically correct
     }
  });
  //Use s to do other things
}
```

Of course the above snippet doesn't work, but is it possible to achieve similar functionality?

Thanks!

Comment: can you not just move the "do other things" part inside the onReceiveValue thingy?

Answer (score 0):

I do it this way:

```
            String js = "window.openDrawer();";

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                mWebView.evaluateJavascript(js, new ValueCallback<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onReceiveValue(String s) {
                        Log.i("MyApp", s);
                    }
                });
            }
```

I don't know if writing '1+2' is enough javascript to get the return value.  You might need to declare the function in javascript, and then have that function return the result of 1+2.

Something like:

```
String js = "func SumIt(int a, int b) { return (a + b); }; SumIt(1, 2);"
```